# Logo animation using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I'm trying to animate a logo that looks like a heartbeat (the following image is not mine, just so you get the idea) :

[image]

What I would like is an animation (about 1 second) where this heartbeat draws from left to right.

What I've done so far: 
- I designed the logo under Sketch 3
- I created about 30 different images named image[i] that represent the different steps

My code: (in init method to preload the textures)

```
let logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image1")
let logoAnimation: SKAction
var textures:[SKTexture] = []
for i in 1...25 {
    textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "image\(i)"))
}
logoAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures,
                                                   timePerFrame: 0.1)
```

And inside didMoveToView :

```
logo.runAction(logoAnimation)
```

But the animation looks kind of bad, laggy...

Is this because I added too many frames ? Or not enough ? Is there a better way to create this kind of animation ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If it's just moving horizontally, I believe you could try to animate a `CGPath`. Using serious of images are not ideal solution.

Comment: @zcui93 : Yeah it's just moving horizontally, but CGPath to animate a complex curve (my logo has curvy edges, not pointy like this one, forgot to mention that) ?

Comment: Have a look at `UIBezierPath` :)

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit just for this animation? If it's just a UIKit app, there is a way of displaying animations based on frames in a UIImageView as well.

Comment: Also, if you are creating a SpriteKit based app, you should preload the textures before running the animation.

Comment: @ZeMoon : I'd like to put the app on the new Apple TV and enable a very simple animation like moving the logo and start the animation over by clicking. This is why I used SpriteKit. Also I've followed a quick tutorial in the past where you animate your "hero" with some textures like this so I tried to adapt my code.

Comment: @ZeMoon : I did preload those textures in an init class, forgot to say it.

Comment: @H4Hugo This is what I was talking about: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageNamed:duration:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just changing the rate of frames per second for the animation? If you have a lot of frames, having it be 0.1 fps might be too slow, try reducing it to 0.05 perhaps?

Comment: Yeah I tried 0.05, I will try to be around 60 fps it should be enough but still, looks laggy :/